# Limit infinite stream of arguments in parameterized test

Tags: java, junit, junit5, parameterized, parameterized-unit-test

I want to write a ParameterizedTest that facilitates a MethodSource to generate a sequence of random values. Now I'm wondering, if there is any *declarative* approach to limit the number of tests run.

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("create64RandomBytes")
// @SomeLimitAnnotation(100) wanted here
void testStuff(byte[] randomBytes) {
    // ...
}

static Stream<Arguments> create64RandomBytes() {
    Random rnd = new Random(42l);
    return Stream.generate(() -> {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
        rnd.nextBytes(bytes);
        return Arguments.of(bytes);
    }).limit(100); // I want to avoid this "limit" call
}
```

Of course I can limit the number of items in the stream, but since `@MethodSource` is built for consuming streams (and surely the JUnit devs are aware of infinite streams), I wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

TLDR: Can I replace the `limit(100)` call with an annotation on my test method?

Comment: I do not know about such feature. If you elaborate *why* you need it, we can think of a different approach to solve your problem. For example you could keep that method `limit`-free and create another method calling `create64RandomBytes().limit(100)` and use this as `@MethodSource`.

Comment: Reusability is obviously one reason, but more important: The method should care about data generation, not about the test setup. I just think it would be cleaner.

Comment: Then I would add method to prepare test setup that limits the results and this method can be a `@MethodSource`.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following be good for you?

```java
@RegisterExtension
static final IntegerResolver integerResolver = new IntegerResolver();

static class IntegerResolver implements ParameterResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(
        ParameterContext parameterContext,
        ExtensionContext extensionContext
    ) {
        return parameterContext.getParameter().getType() == int.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(
        ParameterContext parameterContext,
        ExtensionContext extensionContext
    ) {
        return 100;
    }
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("create64RandomBytes")
void myTest(byte[] randomBytes) {
    // ...
}

static Stream<Arguments> create64RandomBytes(int count) {
    Random rnd = new Random(42l);
    return Stream.generate(() -> {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
        rnd.nextBytes(bytes);
        return Arguments.of(bytes);
    }).limit(count);
}
```